# Download complete directory command line psftp

Tags: download, sftp, command-line-arguments, psftp

I have to move a complete folder from one source to another destination.
I have tried `mget *` and `xcopy`, but neither works. Please suggest some snippets.

I'm using `psftp` to connect the SFTP server.

My code is:

```
cd Remote path
lcd Local path
mget *
bye
```

I have also tried `mget*` and `mget *.*`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Use [`mget -r folder`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-mgetput)
2. If your paths include spaces, do not forget to surround path to double quotes
3. I assume you connect using command line arguments, otherwise you are missing `open` command.